# Making the double linked List generic

Tags: c#

I am working on a C# console application. I am trying to make the double linked list Generic.

I have this class:

```
public class Node<T>
{
    public T data;
    public Node<T> next;
    public Node<T> previous;

    public Node(T d) => (data, next, previous) = (d, null, null);
    public void DisplayNode() => Console.Write("{" + data + "}");
}
```

and the actual double linked class:

```
public class DoubleLinkedList<T>
{
    private Node<T> _first;
    private Node<T> _last;
    // internal Node head;

    public DoubleLinkedList(Node<T> first, Node<T> last) => (_first, _last) = (first, last);
    public DoubleLinkedList() { }

    public bool InsertAfter(int key, T data)
    {
        Node<T> current = _first;

        while (current.data != key)
        {
            current = current.next;
            if (current == null)
                return false;
        }

        Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(data);
        newNode.data = data;

        if (current == _last) (current.next, _last) = (null, newNode);
        else 
        {
            newNode.next = current.next;
            current.next.previous = newNode;
        }

        newNode.previous = current;
        current.next = newNode;

        return true;
    }
```

But I get an error on this line:

```
while (current.data != key)
```

saying:

> CS0019  C# Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and
>   'T'

So my question is: How to solve this error?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, of course I googled first, but this is specific for the double LInked List. So in my eyes it is not a duplicate. And  there is no ans ware in the question. So what is then the ans ware? I have looked at that question. But  no ans ware. Sorry

Comment: So what is then the soluiton?

Comment: Maybe constraints could help [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters] p.s.: Answer*

Comment: Did you take a look at gdoron's answer? Did you try it?

Comment: @SomeWindowsUser. The ans ware(page) you posted don't exist.

Comment: There's some problem with the url, just click on Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide) (If you mean the link)

Comment: Oke, I solved. But I don't understand why don't try to give the answare??

Comment: So I solved by myself. But it is not duplicate!!